# What's the meaning of ‘pull through‘ in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Please, I'd like to know the meaning of **pull through** in the sentence below:

> The new model is one in which products "pull through" profitable services that offer predictable recurring revenue for a long time after they are sold.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the quotation marks around "pull through" part of the original quote, or did you add those yourself? Also, what's the source of this quote, and can we have some more context before and after?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is that the products have services attached to them. If you buy a car then you must buy fuel and you have to get maintenance such as oil change and so on. If you buy a gas furnace to heat your home, then you need to get it serviced in such ways as inspection, replacing the air filters, and so on.

So the original purchase produces a sale for the manufacturer. But it also produces other sales. The car dealership has a service department and maybe even sells fuel. The company that retails the furnace has also got a service department and sells replacement parts.

The image is that the original sale has the additional sales pulled behind it. The original sale pulls the additional sales along with it into the future.